# HTML5-Boilerplate, Compass, Haml and 960 Grid for Rails 3.1.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, compass-sass, 960.gs, html5boilerplate

I've been searching for a working solution for Rails 3.1.x to add HTML5 Boilerplate, Haml, Compass and 960.gs support in a canonical manner (i.e. in a way that fits into the new asset pipeline structure). This used to be fairly easy to achieve in Rails 3.0.x by using the following gems:

- haml-rails
- compass
- html5-boilerplate
- compass-960-plugin

I've looked at several questions / answers both here and elsewhere. However, I haven't been able to find any solid information, and the ways I've tried to piece it together have seemed "hacked together" (in the bad sense) at best. I'd appreciate any clear insight on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The html5-rails gem ?  https://github.com/sporkd/html5-rails

Comment: I ended up using this plus the [compass-960-plugin gem](https://github.com/nextmat/compass-960-plugin). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the rails html5 boilerplate is available: https://github.com/russfrisch/h5bp-rails

here is a gist for compass on rails 3.1.* https://gist.github.com/1184843

Here is a rails 3.1 template that includes 960 and boilerplate: https://github.com/scholarslab/rails31-template

Answer (score 0):

http://compass.handlino.com/
This little app could be useful at least with three of the listed features.